# Using jQuery Datepicker with Backbone: handling select events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, datepicker

Generally, in backbone, if I want to make a function execute on a click, I use the events:

```
events: {
    "click .button": "build",
    "click .name": "name"
},
```

If I try to do this with each individual date of the datepicker, the clicks do not go through. This is because for datepicker you have to use the "onSelect" event built into datepicker:

```
$("#calendar").datepicker(
{
    onSelect: function(){
        //click events...
    }
});
```

This doesn't work for me because I want to be able to define the onSelect function in the backbone events area. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you insisting of using the events property? why not using the "onSelect" handler to trigger an event of your own, or calling another method to handle the selection of date? please specify more of what your'e trying to do :)

Comment: yea, i could definitely do that, but i have to call already defined backbone functions, and afaik there is no way of calling them from onSelect

Comment: What do do you `I have to`..can you shed more light about your goals?

Comment: i have a defined backbone function that i would like to call every time a date is selected.

Comment: So why not simply using the built-in `onSelect` to call this function? I don't see any harm with that. You can also trigger a custom event within the `onSelect`